# Why ModSecurity blocks POST from HttpClient but it doesn't neither from RestSharp nor Postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp, mod-security

I have a REST API which is hosted by my local provider. It has a Plesk panel installed and ModSecurity, which is turned on by default. When I try to make GET request everything works just fine. It gets worse when I try to make POST request.

If I use built-in HttpClient, my request gets rejected by ModSecurity with HTTP502.3 error. The request is made with the following code:

```
var content = JsonContent.Create(new
    {
        PatientCode = "123456",
        Password = "123456" / auth data
    });
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }; // mock for invalid SSL
    using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/post", content);
        try
        {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationResponse>(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What is more interesting, the following code with RestSharp works just fine and I get correct response:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://example.com/post")
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true // mock for invalid SSL
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest()
    .AddJsonBody(new
    {
        PatientCode = "123456",
        Password = "123456" // auth data
    });
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync<AuthenticationResponse>(request);
```

Also, if I try to make such a request with Postman, it still works fine (Postman generates this HTTP code for my request):

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 58

{
    "PatientCode":"123456",
    "Password":"123456"
}
```

So what's the matter? Why does ModSecurity blocks POST from HttpClient but doesn't block requests neither from RestSharp nor from Postman?

Comment: Log `errors` in `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` to see potential problems you encounter. For example, maybe you use a different host name?

Comment: What makes you think it's being blocked? [502 Bad Gateway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) doesn't generally indicate that.

Comment: This doesn't have to be caused by ModSecurity. Compare the requests. Most likely some different headers that ModSecurity or the upstream server requires. User-Agent would be my first guess.

Comment: @madmonk46, I have several reasons:
1) the rejected request doesn't hit my REST API, I don't see it in logs, but I see it in provider's logs of unsuccessful requests
2) the request passes and returns valid result after I ask my provider to disable ModSecurity

Comment: @NineBerry, I think that's not the case, because RestSharp has the same setup with ignoring SSL errors and it works. Also I tried passing hostname into HttpClient and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any other information back? If it's IIS that's returning that error you should get a bit more information than that

Comment: @madmonk46, that's the main problem - I don't get much of information back. I have only response which I can see in my C# code and an xml file which contains different data like Url, SiteId, AppPoolId, RawConnId and I don't know how this info is related with my error.

Comment: That's how response looks 
{StatusCode: 502, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Gateway', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
  Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2022 12:02:51 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 3717
}}

Comment: CRS Dev-On-Duty here. Normally ModSecurity doesn't block with a 502 Bad Gateway, but with a 403 Forbidden or sometimes 400 Bad Request. So it's probably not a problem with the ModSecurity Core Rule Set rules. Are you able to get any error logs from your provider? Is ModSecurity enabled by adding a reverse proxy? So maybe there is an error in the configuration to the backend, like for example missing proxy_ssl settings?

Comment: @franbuehler, I can't get any more information because my provider stopped supporting all the Windows hostings and all that I've been left with is a bunch of pre-installed debug tools which seem to be uninformative. I don't even think about changing ModSecurity settings because I can't do it, I was mostly looking for differences between working and broken requests. And I don't quiet got it :(